# Getting users geolocation latitude and longitude through ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I temporarily retrieve a users latitude and longitude in a controller action method.

I have a Model with the attributes lat and lng which I obtained through google maps api. I now need to get a distance between these model and the users current location.

Comment: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder